# Load Js file Application loads

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have to load an external Javascript file that needs to be loaded before an application startup page loads. And the variables in js file needs to be used by all the jsp files in the application...

How can I achieve this?

Comment: JS is on client side and JSP on server side. You can't access those variables in your JSP.

Comment: I need to fill js variables into the html form in different files

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can load an external `script`:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = function () {
    //do stuff with the script
};
script.src = something;

document.head.appendChild(script); //or something of the likes
```

If you have to execute some Javascript code after the `script` is loaded, then wrap a `function` around your Javascript and call it from the `onload` of the `script`.